# SWIFT 2 : Annotation with link to new page.

Tags: dictionary, view, annotations, mapkit, swift2

First of all, yes. I know this question has been asked many times before but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I would like to add an arrow (symbol) to my annotation so that after I press it it opens a new page (see image).

I can add the annotations to the map created from an Array I retrieve, but I can't seem to get the button on the annotation and so I als o can't open the new page.

What i've got so far:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if pinView == nil {
            //println("Pinview was nil")
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        }

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign in it

        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button


        return pinView
    }
```

Also if I try to debug this, the code of func mapview doesn't seem to run.

Code to create the annotation:

func getMapAnnotations() -> [Activity] {
    var annotations:Array = Activity

```
    do {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http:/URL")!)

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonData as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

            let longtitudeItem = (anItem["LONGTITUDE"] as! NSString).doubleValue;
            let latitudeItem = (anItem["LATITUDE"] as! NSString).doubleValue;
            let name = anItem["NAME"] as! String;
            let description = anItem["DESCRIPTION"] as! String;

            // do something with the data retrieved:
            let theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01 , 0.01)
            // let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
            let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudeItem , longitude:longtitudeItem)
            let theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, theSpan)

            mapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

            let anotation = Activity(latitude: latitudeItem, longitude: longtitudeItem)
            anotation.title = name
            anotation.subtitle = description

            annotations.append(anotation)


        }  } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error)

    }
    return annotations }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's driving me insane!

Kr,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set delegate of mapView? `viewForAnnotation` method is called?

See also my sample code: https://github.com/koogawa/MKMapViewSample/blob/master/MKMapViewSample/ViewController.swift

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you check my code to see if you can find what i'm missing?

I'm very new to iOS development, so i'm sure there is a lot I can improve, but for now I just want to check how to add the button and open a new view. 

Code:
https://github.com/the-traveller/Globe_connect/blob/master/globe_connect/RootViewController.swift

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, It's fixed. You were right about the "delegate" I never realised (or found any information) that you had to add the delegate in the storyboard on your map view.

Thank you.

Comment: how to make the annotation open a new page with unique key for every pin i have in my map?